# How to update the local repository from remote server successfully?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-rebase

In `github.org`, `B` has a repository named `helloworld.git`, and two branches.

```
    http://github.org/B/helloworld.git:
        master
        dev   --> always updated.
```

I forked the repository into my account `A`, and create a new branch named `test`.

```
    http://githu.org/A/helloworld.git:
        master
        dev
        test  --> do my work and commit it into this branch
```

and I have checked out the repository into my local machine:

```
    git clone http://github.org/A/helloworld.git
    git checkout master
    git checkout dev
    git checkout test
```

then, I want to keep my local repository updated from `B`'s repository:

```
    git remote add upstream http://github.org/B/helloworld.git
    git fetch upstream
    git checkout master
    git merge upstream/master
    git checkout dev
    git merge upstream/dev
```

and, if I using `git status`, it says `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev' by 22 commits.`

But, when I made a commit, there is a error:

```
    git checkout test
    (do some modifications in doc/Readme.md)
    git add doc/Readme.md
    git commit -am "modified doc/Readme.md"
    git push origin test
```

There is an error:

```
    fatal: Authentication failed
```

What's wrong? How could I do this work successfully?  Thanks!

Comment: The answer is to add `SSH` keys into the `github`: generate `id_dsa.pub`, then copy its content into the `github` account, then `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:A/helloworld.git`, then `git push origin test`. It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an https url for your origin repo, referencing your fork, then you need to enter your `A` GitHub account login/password as credential.

Check your current remote with `git remote -v`

I prefer adding the username in the url itself in order to enter only the password:

```
git remote set-url origin http://A@github.org/A/helloworld.git
```